# Tomcat 6 and log4j application logging produce no output

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, tomcat6

I'm trying to get log4j application (webapp) logging working in a Tomcat 6 app. I have log4j-1.2.15.jar in my WEB-INF directory, log4j.dtd and log4j.xml in WEB-INF/classes.

My log4j.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
<appender name="massAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="100KB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2" />
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/mass.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}: %m%n " />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.company.mass">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="massAppender"/>
</category>

<root>
     <appender-ref ref="massAppender" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

My servlet is in the package:

```
package com.company.mass;
```

where the logger is declared as:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Handler.class);
```

and at the top of my doGet(...) method there is:

```
logger.error("foo");
```

When I deploy the app in Tomcat and go to the servlet, it works correctly. I even get a mass.log file, but nothing gets put in it. It doesn't show up in any other logs either, and there are no obvious errors. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: have you checked the catalina.out log?

Comment: I do not have a catalina.out. My cataline.2009-05-27.log has the standard startup stuff in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that log4j is actually using your `log4j.xml` for it's configuration, and not another file on the classpath?

Enable the system property `-Dlog4j.debug` to have log4j print out information about exactly which configuration file it is using.

Comment: well here is a dumb question, are you absolutely positive that the logging lines are even getting hit when the code is executed? Also btw, adding the appender twice (to root and to "com.company.mass") will result in log messages sent to the appender twice

Comment: Stupid question but a good one. I was hitting the default index.jsp that Maven produces which coincidentally produced the exact same output (Hello World) that my servelt produced. Going to a page with logging made logging work.

Comment: in my experience it worked best when the log4j.properties file was in the same directory with the log4j.jar file.  not sure if its the same with a .xml config but I bet it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a priority in your root logger.  Try this config

```
<category name="com.company.mass">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/> 
    <!-- no need to specify appender again here -->
</category>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO"/> 
     <appender-ref ref="massAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, those changes did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line :

```
<param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
```

to your massAppender config

and this line

```
<priority value ="debug"/>
```

inside your root definition

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.

Comment: my Tomcat6 doesn't even have a config file with "massAppender" in it.

Answer (score 0):

When I've encountered this problem I was able to resolve it by adding `common-logging.jar` to my deployment assembly.